# Solid method to send data and confirm by both sides with Jquery and Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django, cordova

I'm developing an application under PhoneGap, and my application send orders (item, costumer, etc) from MobileDevice to Server (in python django). I use jQuery Ajax to send orders to my server, and server response with correct operation ID to MobileDevice, but if Internet Network is not fine, response don't came back to MobileDevice or server give Correct operation ID, but never arrive response to Mobile Device.

I'm looking for a method for confirm solid communications and I dont know if my system is reliable (3 steps):

1.- `MobileDevice:` Send Order (Item's) and Order Auth via AJAX, wait completed, etc.

2.- `Server in Django:` Receive Order and Data, validate and process order, finally send OK.

3.-`MobileDevice:` Receive OK confirmation and check order as Sended and correct.

Should be it correct? 
What are other methods to do something like it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [REST](http://www.restapitutorial.com/) and [Tastypie](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html), this would do the job.

**Edit**:

Just a thought, you're building this on top of TCP/IP – a stack of protocols that was designed so that any network based on it could withstand a nuclear attack. It's been doing damn well for almost 40 years now, it's pretty solid. Again, just a thought. :-)

Comment: Well, I use similar tech, because I use URIs that provide services, like update items, sync data, send orders, but, for example I have one AJAX request to put JSON in Django server and then process it, for instance server response with confirmation, but sometimes Internet Network fails and after timeout, app say -reach timeout- but server have received order and I dont know if server do it right or not. Thanks

Comment: The solution is to build a very robust API that can take all kinds of crap. Split the task up into separate chunks; you should expect and test for failure at every point along the way. For example, what happens if the customer's battery goes flat when they're in the middle of an order? don't make it necessary for a long call chain to be completely satisfied before you do anything, have discreet ‘atomic/transactional’ units.

Comment: Thanks matt, i'll do what you recommend me .